# Allowing LAN users to send requests to a printer

Tags: windows-7, lan, network-printer

I have a Xerox Phaser3500N printer. I have connected it to my PC using a USB cable. I now want users on my LAN to to be able to send print jobs to this printer via my machine. How can I set this up?

Comment: Oh I'd missed the fact that you'd tagged this with Windows 7. I've deleted my previous comment.

Answer (score 3):

That model has a built-in network interface. It will probably be easier and more reliable to connect it directly to the network and set up your machine (and the others) to use it as a network printer.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you can probably use a LAN printer sharing by Microsoft. OR... you could use the infamous [Google Cloud Print](http://www.google.com/cloudprint/learn/) feature. All it requires is you to have a Google Account, and the well known [Google Chrome Browser](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/) installed on the computer connected to the printer.

This would be the easiest method, but if you absolutely need LAN networking, I don't know.

Hope this helps.